# My CSS does not display the changes to my HTML. I cannot see what's wrong. Any fixes?

Tags: html, css

All files (video.html, video.css, video.js) are under the same folder and correct link rel. I just cannot figure out why my CSS is not displaying the changes to HTML.

### video.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- custom css file line  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="video.css">
</head>
```

### video.css

```
.container{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap:20px;
}
.container .main-video-container{
    flex:1 1 700px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;

}

.container .main-video-container .main-video{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any elements in the body of your page that use the classes you have listed in your CSS file?  Do you have something the body section like <div class="container">....

Comment: Yes I do have them

Comment: Please add the entire HTML.

Comment: can you printscreen your folders so we can see all your folders.. and what are you using to run this? I mean server wise or where are you running this?

Comment: Post the full html code and css.